# is there a function that can take values from function parameter and apply it in a statement in python?

Tags: python, opencv

```
def load_img(img):
    img = cv.imread(r"C:\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\Computer-Vision-with-Python\DATA\ **dynamic_img** ")    
    img = cv.cvtColor(img ,cv.COLOR_BRG2RGB)
    return img
```

so this is the function.... what I want to do is call the function with any image from the destination folder and it should replace that `dynamic_img` with the name of the image

THANK YOU.

Comment: look up string concatenation with a variable!

Comment: Do you have a problem finding the files or don't you know `os.path.join(r"C:\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\Computer-Vision-with-Python\DATA", dynamic_img)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to find all images in the directory:

```
import os

path = 'c:\\Users\\OneDrive\\and_so_on'

files = []
# r=root, d=directories, f = files
for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    for file in f:
        if '.jpg' in file:
            files.append(os.path.join(r, file))
```

Then you can just iterate over `files`.